# How can i adjust the click-area around my checkbox?

Tags: html, css, angular

im currently stuck with this formating issue in my angular application.
As you can see in the attached images, there is a problem with the clickable area around my checkboxes.

[image]
[image]

I basically want to adjust the clickable area to the size of the checkbox.

In the 2nd image I highlighted the current area with a background-color: aquamarine to make it more clear.

My SCSS code looks like this. I have a feeling, that this should be an easy task, but I'm somewhat missing something in detail.

```
.date-checkbox {
display: inline;
float: right;
margin-right: -24px;
margin-top: -23px;
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
}

.disable-date {
opacity: 0.5;
pointer-events: none;
}

.enum-checkbox {
display: inline;
float: right;
margin-right: -24px;
margin-top: -23px;
-webkit-transform: scale(2);
}

/* The container */
.container {
cursor: pointer;
  }

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
opacity: 0;
cursor: pointer;
height: 0;
width: 0;
  }

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
position: absolute;
top: 4px;
left: 25px;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
background-color: blue;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
background-color: blue;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
 background-color: blue;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
 display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
left: 5px;
top: 2px;
width: 5px;
height: 10px;
border: solid white;
border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="enum-checkbox">
    <label class="container">
       <input type="checkbox" (click)="IncludeExcludeProp(groupobject[g.PROPS.title], $event)"
        title="Include in search" />
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your `HTML` along with some sort of working example.

Comment: added the HTML code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since clicking the label essentially clicks the checkbox, I would add `padding` or `width` to the `label` surrounding the checkbox so that it extends as far as you need your clickable area to be.

Note that, for accessibility, I've added `aria-label` to the checkbox. The `title` attribute is ignored by screen readers and the `label` would otherwise contain no helpful information about the checkbox.

[image]

```css
.lbl-checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5em;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<label class="lbl-checkbox">
  <input aria-label="an appropriate label" type="checkbox">
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing up this idea! It helped to think about the issue and I managed to adjust it to my specific code.

Comment: What an excellent approach, thank you!